# Error: No such device and Error: unknown file system

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu, filesystem

I was installing Lubuntu on an external flash drive (not wise) and then when I go to boot back up on Ubuntu this pops up.

[image]

Comment: I assume that Ubuntu was installed on your main hard disk. If so, you accidentally built Lubuntu on your hard disk, not the flash drive.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you did; you tried to install Lubuntu onto a flash drive (I don't see a problem there), but your chosen grub device (grub stage 0 is the MBR of what your system boots) now points to a UUID of 6fa7d... that is no longer connected (ie. pointing to the /boot/grub/ on a disconnected device; your flash drive possibly?). If you have Ubuntu installed; you need to have it point to the always-connected hdd/sdd (and had Lubuntu's grub written to thumb-drive), but I won't give further advice as I'm guessing at what you did, clarification may help.

Comment: I hope this clarifies some things:    I was trying to restore an old pc by making it boot into Lubuntu which is installed on a flash drive(#1). I said that is not wise because it is extremely slow to boot and do basic task. I had a live Lubuntu flashdrive(#2) lying around and decided to put it to use by installing it to previously mentioned flashdrive(#1). I was doing this all while my ubuntu drive is plugged in. When I took out flashdrives(#1 & 2) and tried to boot back into Ubuntu I recieved the message on the picture. Hopefully this makes sense. Do you think I installed Lubuntu over my hdd?

Answer (score 0):

Like @guiverc suggests, it looks like you accidentially installed the thumbdrive's bootloader onto your harddisk.

Does your PC boot Lubuntu when you reconnect flashdrive#1 (the one you installed Lubuntu to) but set your BIOS to boot from your ubuntu-harddisk?

If yes, remove your Lubuntu-Drive again and reboot to the error message. From there you can use this guide:

https://linuxhint.com/grub_rescue_ubuntu_1804/

to restore Grub into booting Ubuntu. It explains how to use the grub cli to find your original Ubuntu-installation, boot into it manually and reinstall grub.